# Disabling Javascript CSS3 transitions issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions

OK, so the site I'm working on has entered a phase in which it needs to work without any javascript loaded - no jQuery, no JS, no special plugins - just pure HTML5 / CSS3. The reason for this is to reduce the javascript overhead and only use javascript for non-critical functionality. As such, all links now load pages instead of using AJAX, with a fallback for reduced traffic and file sizes using AJAX.

The problem I ran into today was in using a :hover state to show a dropdown form - applying a transition to the dropdown so it doesn't immediately disappear when moving the cursor outside of the dropdown. However, with javascript disabled (tested in both Chrome and Firefox), the dropdown displays on the page briefly on load before becoming hidden. What happens is the transition delay is being used on page load, and once that timer expires, the dropdown disappears.

Here's the CSS:

```
.topmenu {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    right:0;
    width:29%;
    z-index:10;
    /*display:none;*/
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition:visibility .1s 2s, opacity .1s 2s;
}
.right .hover + .topmenu, .right:hover .topmenu {
    transition-delay:.1s;
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1;
}
```

My question is - is there a way to hide the submenu (.topmenu) on page load without using javascript? It works as expected with javascript turned on, but the point is to make it work without javascript, even on page load. Once it disappears, it works as expected.

Second question is - do Firefox and Chrome both use javascript to parse CSS? Doesn't make any sense for this behavior to be inherent. Just for a little more background, I tried Firefox with the Noscript plugin, and Chrome using both settings and Quick Javascript Switch (I disabled QJS and tried the native javascript disabler switch to see if this was a plugin / extension issue).

**UPDATE:** Here's an actual code sampling, but in jsfiddle the problem isn't shown because you can't run jsfiddle without javascript enabled. At least you can see the code though and maybe provide some insight from that.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lazerblade01/pL2s7s19/6/)

Comment: The `transition-delay` should not be getting applied on page load unless you are hovering the `.right` or are somehow attaching the `.hover` class to its child. Basically there needs to be a state change for transition to get applied. Can you create a demo so that we can see the issue?

Comment: @Harry, I realize that the transition delay shouldn't be applied, and yet it is. I am not sure why, which is what I was looking for information on. Please note that this only happens with javascript turned off in the browser. Funny thing is IE11 doesn't do this - as far as I can tell, only Chrome and Firefox do. I'm not sure where I can make a demo that allows for no javascript - does jsfiddle allow that?

Comment: Hmm, sounds pretty tricky and complicated. Without seeing code in action we can't really say why it happens and as you said, it would be tough to create a no JS demo also. Maybe you'd have to debug yourself (or) get somebody who can access your machine to help out.